# What does this black lever next to the overhead panel on the Airbus 320 do?

Tags: airbus-a320, feature-identification

What does this do?
It's located next to the overhead panel of an A320 cockpit.

[image]

[image: unknown lever]

Comment: @Bianfable it appears to be to the bottom-right hand side of the overhead panel. Next to the ventilation controls.

Comment: I’d guess it *is* the ventilation control. Probably opens and closes the louvers for that overhead vent.  Interesting that the pilot doesn’t seem to have one too.

Comment: Prob due to the HUD

Comment: Why not give it a yank and see what happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a secret and Airbus does not want you to know.)

Here is the cockpit general arrangement view from the Airbus Flightdeck and Systems briefing for Pilots which labels the visor and rope storage compartment, but the pdf in every version that I looked at only showed descriptions for controls but the graphic did not render. Anywhere.

[image]

Next I looked at a flight crew operating manual, where the control is not even pictured but everything around it is. This may be only useful in determining what it is not.

[image]

I looked at photos including this one from a German Wings A320 where there are two, so it cannot be that critical a control if this has two, your photo has one, some apparently have none, and nowhere is it documented.

[image]

The best answer that I found comes from the cabin crew operators manual which shows ventilation ducts going right through that area on both sides of the overhead panel, terminating in a plenum above each of the pilot and copilot windscreens and showing airflow from those plenums across the windscreens. Since the control is a variable +/- from your picture, it stands to reason that it is a simple airflow control for defogging the windscreen.

[image]

Comment: +1 for opening sentence --